# Convert IGrouping to IQueryable in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, igrouping

```
if (model.ConnectedToOtherProfilesId != 0)
{
      var fooGroup = fans.GroupBy(x => x.FanId)
                         .Where(x => x.Any(z => z.ProfileId == model.ConnectedToOtherProfilesId));

      var fooGroup2 = fooGroup.Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1);
}
```

What I need is to put the results from `fooGroup2` [`IQueryable<IGrouping<int,PF>`] into fans which is `IQueryiable<PF>`

Something like this:

```
fans = fooGroup2;
```

Comment: Do you mean `fooGroup2.SelectMany(x => x);`, your question is not clear?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `SelectMany`.

```
//IQueryable<PF>
var fooGroup2 = fooGroup.Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1)
                        .SelectMany(pf => pf);
```